# Find a number in a another number

Tags: python, search, numbers

How can I find if a number is in another number and it's location in python?

Example: finding if 58 is in 45896 and its location?

Output: True and 2 Place

PS: Is there a way without invoking strings. Just with number?

Comment: Hint: are you familiar with taking the modulus?  Try `1235 % 100` at the console, and think about how you could get the appropriate purely numeric "substrings" to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're asking for a method where the values are not converted to strings.
Beware, I've not tested this for all possible cases. So you may be able to find bugs. If and when you do, please let me know so I can fix this.

```
def find_length(num):
    # If number is 0, return the length as 1.
    if num == 0:
        return 1
    length = 0

    # Loop over the number by dividing it by 10
    # and incrementing the length counter.

    while num != 0:
        length += 1
        num /= 10
    return length

def find_inside(num1, num2):
    # Trivial case, when the numbers are same.
    if num1 == num2:
        return (True, 1)

    len_n2 = find_length(num2)
    place = find_length(num1)

    # Iterate over the numbers, extracting the last
    # n digits everytime, where n is length of num2
    # Keep dividing the original number by 10 and
    # decrementing place everytime.

    while num1 != 0:
        if num2 == (num1 % (10 ** len_n2)):
            return (True, place - len_n2 + 1)
        num1 /= 10
        place -= 1
    return (False, -1)
```

Some test cases (Trivial):

```
>>> find_inside(10, 0)
(True, 2)
>>> find_inside(3456, 98)
(False, -1)
>>> find_inside(4589678, 58)
(True, 2)
>>> find_inside(10, 1)
(True, 1)
```

Comment: So you're using Python3?

Comment: Division operator was changed in Py3. Try replacing all division signs in my code with `//`.

Comment: Also
find_inside(10,0) returns 
(True, 325)

Comment: Not according to the test cases here. Did you change the division operators?

Comment: Works but it finds the last place not the first.
If there are repetitions like 1545123452 it will show the place of the last 45.

Comment: @KillerB: Yes, well, you could easily reverse the number, then! ;)

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> x=str(45896)
>>> str(58) in x
True
>>> x.index(str('58')) + 1
2
```

Comment: I understand turning it inot a string but is there a way for numbers like there is for strings?

Answer (score 0):

Another way using re:

```
re.search('58','45896').start()+1
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest `re` for searching for literal strings. `str` already has a variety of methods to do that.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it without invoking strings?

Comment: No, re module in always feed by str

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
>>> x=45896
>>> y=58
>>> str(x).index(str(y))+1 if str(y) in str(x) else -1
2
>>>
```

Alternative (uses `str(...)` only for length!):

```
x=45896
y=58

yLength = len(str(y)) #you need the size! 
t = 10**yLength
found = "false"
position = 0

while x > 0:
    position = position +1
    if(x%t == y):
        found = "true"
        break
    x = x/10

print found
print str(position - 1)
```

**NOTE**:  You can get the size easily without using `str(...)`, but I will leave you to write that code.

Comment: @KillerB  Updated to fit your requirements

Comment: You could always find the length without the `str` call. ;)

Comment: @SukritKalra I know, but I didn't want to go out the way to write something OP should be able to figure out easily

Answer (score 0):

If you want work without strings you will like this approach:

```
import math

original = 45896
find = 58

org_dgt = int(math.log10(original))+1
fnd_dgt = int(math.log10(find))+1

count = 1
found = False
while not found:
    curr_dgt = org_dgt-fnd_dgt
    if curr_dgt < 0:
        break
    if int((original%(10**org_dgt))/(10**(curr_dgt))) == find:
        found = True
        break
    org_dgt -= 1
    count += 1

if found:
    print count
else:
    print 'Not Found'
```